# Save something to vs Save something on/onto

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, difference

I would like to know the difference in meaning between "**to save something to**" and "**to save something on/onto**" in the context of *technology*.

Here are a couple of example sentences:

> 1. **Save** the file **to** the hard disk.
> 2. You can **save** the data **on**/**onto** your hard disk.

What does it imply "**to save something to**"?
What does it imply "**to save something on/onto**"?
Also, I wonder if "**to save something ONTO**" is idiomatic.

If I say

> "Save the photo/document/audio **TO/ON** the
>   computer/phone/camera/ipad" (do they both mean the same?)
>
> "Save the photo/document/audio **TO/ON** 'C:\Windows\' " (do
>   they both mean the same?)

Answer (score 2):

All of these expressions are possible and mean the same.

With modern technology, there is often variation because the language hasn't settled on one way of saying something.

Comment: If I say"Save the photo/document/audio **TO/ON** the computer/phone/camera/ipad", do they both mean the same? 
If I say"Save the photo/document/audio **TO/ON** 'C:\Windows\' ", do they both mean the same?

Answer (score -1):

**Save to** is more straightforward when you want to **put** something into a container. **Save on** can have other uses such as **Save on time** (to meet a deadline) or **Save on your budget** (to spend less or avail discount).